# How to administer a remote java program?

Tags: java, rmi, cajo

I want to build a GUI to administer a remotely executing java program (view status of executing tasks, load/start/stop tasks), but nothing complicated.

My best idea so far is to use [CAJO](http://java.net/projects/cajo/pages/Home).

Is there another approach that might be superior?

The Java program is a standard Java SE executable.  It is not part of a web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way is to use JMX. You can access JMX over HTTP as well. This is the cheapest but not the nicer solution because UI of the standard JMX console is not the best UI I have ever seen :).

Comment: On the other hand, with JMX you already have a UI and don't have to write it yourself. I was just about to add this to my answer, but +1 to you :)

Comment: Thank you!  JMX appears to be exactly what I want.  Here's a link to a [getting started](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jmx.html) guide.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a simple ReSTful API on the remote JVM might be a simpler alternative, depending on the circumstances. JAX-RS makes it very easy. I have experience with [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/getting-started.html) myself, and you can get it up and running in about five minutes.